# How to make node.js automatically execute commands when I run the server?

Tags: javascript, command, line

for example I am constantly having to write:
"node app.js &" to start the server and then writing this manually afterwards:
"watchify main.js -o bundle.js -v"  to start the watchify script

is there a way I can execute that automatically? and other lines after that so I dont have to keep manually typing/copy and pasting the lines individually everytime I run my server

Answer (score 0):

Add a scripts section to your `package.json` file.

Then call  `npm run <ScriptName>`

if you're looking for bash specific example, the following will do the trick:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "run-and-watch": "node app.js & watchify main.js -o bundle.js -v"
}
...
```

`npm run run-and-watch`

If you want a cross-platform option, there are npm modules such as *[concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)* and *[npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)* that should help you out.